# Vue: what is the best way to avoid TypeError inside computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Imagine that you have some nested state in store. E.g.

```
state: {
    some: {
        really: {
             deep: true
        }
    }
}
```

And you map it in your component, and want to set some quick computed for shortcut or something else:

```
computed: {
    // pls don't tell me that I can map only `deep` 
    // it's not the point of this question
    ...mapState('some'),
    isDeep() {
        return this.some.really.deep
    }
}
```

And the problem here is that at any level state could be `null` instead of object. E.g. `some` became `null`. Then you will get error when access property `really` of `null`.

And my **question is**: what is the best practice to avoid such thing? For example, I've used `_.get` from lodash to avoid it. But I think _.get is really bad when used with TypeScript. Because you should write props as strings, e.g.

```
isDeep() {
    return _.get(this.some, 'really.deep')
}
```

Another way I've seen is just to use try/catch. It looks more refactor-friendly and typesafer, but a little more ugly as well. And also I'm not really sure if it's ok in terms of performance to put try/catch in any potentially unsafe property access:

```
isDeep() {
    try {
        return this.some.really.deep
    } catch (_) {
        return false
    }
}
```

And the most obvious but sometimes hardly readable option is:

```
isDeep() {
    return this.some && this.some.really && this.some.really.deep
}
```

So what do you think is the best way to handle that case and avoid `TypeError: Cannot read property 'blah' of null` inside computed properties? Which do you use in your projects?

Comment: What you call hardly readable is idiomatic JavaScript. You'll get used to it. `&&` is also known as the guard operator and if you think about it that way it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: There is a babel plugin that enables optional chaining operator `this.some?.really?.deep` https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining. Or [idx.macro](https://www.npmjs.com/package/idx.macro) that works with typescript.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I agree and I think it works best, but often it doesn't look so good as in my question.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, I'll check it out.